# Azure: can memebrship and my tables share the same connection string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I put membership tables and my tables in the same database, thus I'm using only one 1 **connection string** and one **DBContext** class. I'using Ado.Net EF Code First with migration. Below is my **local connection**.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
     Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

On my local machine, thinks are working perfectly, i.e. the first time I try to read/write data to/from the database, code first create the database and its tables.

However, when I upload the application to Azure Websites, only the membership tables are created. I need to run manually **DDL** and **insert** statements as well to recreate my local database.

Any reasons for that?

Answer (score 0):

The microsoft membership tables created with aspnet_regsql.exe are not compatible with Azure.

You shoud use the scripts from this [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191/). If you want to use CF migrations you have to provide the SQL statements in a manual configuration file. This could be achieved by creating a new (empty) migration with `Add-Migration ASPNETMembershipFiles` and by adding appropriate `Sql()` calls. We started this effort and after some hours of work we moved to the other option (see below).

The other option is to run the script from the support article manually and leave those tables out of CF migration.